# I have a python code that generates multiple images, is there a way to save all the images that are generated to a pdf file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

The images are generated using the code, plt.show(block=False).

```
# plot normal curve for comparison
    mu, std = stats.norm.fit(d3["DepthDiff"])
    xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
    x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
    p = stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, std)
    sns.lineplot(x=x, y=p, color="orange", ax=ax)
    plt.show(block=False)

    # -- Boxplot of DepthDiff --
    _, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 3))
    sns.boxplot(x=d3["DepthDiff"], orient="h", showmeans=True)
    plt.show(block=False)
```

I would like to save the two images generated into a pdf called gallery.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a Python PDF Library. I don't have a specific recommendation but pypdf2 came up first in a search. Here is a guide with an image example, and a link to the github.

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/09/pypdf2-library-for-working-with-pdf-files-in-python/

https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2